# what is wrong in this code trying to print Fibonacci series in reverse order

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, reverse, fibonacci

tried to take terms in array and printed that array but expected output is different from my output not able to find the logic behind it.

code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int num;
  int t1=0;
  int t2=1;
  int next;
  cin>>num;
  int arr[num];

  for (int i = num-1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    if (i == num-t1-1)
    {
      arr[i] = t1;
      continue;
    }
    if (i == num-t2-1)
    {
      arr[i] = t2;
      continue;
    }
    next = t1+t2;
    arr[i] = next;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = next;
  }
  
  for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
    {
      cout<<arr[j]<<" ";
    }
    
  return 0;
}
```

what is wrong in this code?
output if user enter 20 is

- 20
- 2584 1597 987 610 377 233 144 89 55 34 21 8 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0

one additional 8 is coming in between 21 and 13.

### But expected output should be

- 20
- 4181 2584 1597 987 610 377 233 144 89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages. One difference is that [C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: As for your problem, generate numbers in the normal order, then *print* in reverse order. Usually much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a good example of how code should not be written.:)

It is very difficult to understand your code. It's a rule that badly readable code is bound to contain bugs.

For example there are used three variables `t1`, `t2` and `next` to assign values to elements of the array

```
arr[i] = t1;
//...
arr[i] = t2;
//...
arr[i] = next;
```

and it is not clear for which value of the variable `i` there will be used one of the assignments.

For starters variable length arrays like this

```
int arr[num];
```

are not a standard C++ feature. Instead you should use standard container `std::vector`.

That is if you write a C++ program you should use features provided by the C++ language.

Your code is invalid. For example when `i` is equal to `11` then `t1` is equal tp `8`. and this if statement

```
if (i == num-t1-1)
```

in this case is equivalent to

```
if ( 11 == 20-8-1)
```

or

```
if ( 11 == 11 )
```

and the value of `t1` is written in the array element `arr[11]`. instead of writing the value `21`.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how your assignment can be performed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;

    if (std::cin >> n && n != 0)
    {
        std::vector<unsigned long long> v( n );

        std::pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> fibonacci( 0, 1 );

        for (auto first = std::rbegin( v ), last = std::rend( v ); first != last; ++first)
        {
            *first = fibonacci.first;
            fibonacci.first = 
                std::exchange( fibonacci.second, fibonacci.first + fibonacci.second );
        }

        for (const auto &item : v)
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is the same as expected.

```
20
4181 2584 1597 987 610 377 233 144 89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0
```

Pay attention that instead of using the signed type `int` for the variable `num` you should use an unsigned integer type as for example `unsigned int`. And to avoid an overflow the variables `t1` and `t2` should have at least the type `unsigned long long int`.

In the provided demonstration program this declaration

```
std::pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> fibonacci( 0, 1 );
```

makes it clear that the program deals with fibonacci numbers.

Comment: As a beginner, I am still learning and I value your patience and constructive feedback. thankyou for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to place `t1` and `t2` at the last two indices of `arr`. Those indices are not `num-t1-1` and `num-t2-1`, but `num-1` and `num-2`.

Rather than special casing the loop, it is easier to assign them outside of the loop and start the loop at the 3rd last.

`int arr[num];` is not valid C++. Use `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays.

Last but not least, the logic in your loop looks too complicated. You only need to use the recurrence relation directly (well, ok reversed) `arr[i] = arr[i+1] + arr[i+2]`, no additional variables are needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int num;
  std::cin >> num;

  if (num < 3) {
      std::cout << "num is too small\n";
      return 1;
  }

  std::vector<int> arr(num);

  arr[num-1] = 0;
  arr[num-2] = 1;

  for (int i = num-3; i >= 0; i--) {    
    arr[i] = arr[i+1] + arr[i+2];
  }
  
  for(const auto& e : arr) {
      std::cout << e << " ";
  }       

}
```

For further reading I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector,
[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice),
[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard),and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).